# how to put sql script into Stored procedure

Tags: sql

```
USE RAUSDXT02

--drop table ##tbl_STORE_LIST

select store_code  INTO ##tbl_STORE_LIST from store

where 

store_code not in ('722','803','8000') and 

date_closed is  NULL and 

global_tax_code is not NULL and

store_type='S'

--select * from ##tbl_STORE_LIST

DECLARE @store_code nvarchar(20)


DECLARE store_code_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT store_code FROM ##tbl_STORE_LIST
OPEN store_code_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM store_code_cursor INTO @store_code


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
EXEC XP_CmdShell 'BCP "Select * from  ##tbl_STORE_LIST" queryout "\\dalsqlposdev2\RADATA\Debopam\TRAFFIC\ACTIVESTORES.txt" -c -T'

    FETCH NEXT FROM store_code_cursor INTO @store_code
END
CLOSE store_code_cursor
DEALLOCATE store_code_cursor

DROP TABLE ##tbl_STORE_LIST
```

How to put this above script in an SP so that the query can be run in one command like EXEC SP_name.

Comment: please format your code correctly before posting

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap with the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Name AS 
BEGIN


... your code



END
```